# Do ships in Pirates of Caribbean get a speed boost from magic?

Tags: magic, pirates-of-the-caribbean, vehicles

In the *Pirates of the Caribbean* series, the ships have magical properties. Do these properties affect their speeds? That is, do they travel faster than equivalent real-world sailing ships?

Comment: They travel across the Pacific in 14 parsecs! Oops wrong franchise....

Comment: I dare say as we never get any concrete dates or travel times during the franchise it will be VERY hard to say

Comment: They sail at the speed of plot.

Comment: It’s not necessary to establish concrete dates and travel times if someone can cite, for example, a character saying “How could that ship possibly have gotten here so fast?”

Comment: From the curse of the Black Pearl film, it is simply stated that the Black Pearl is the fastest ship on the waters. There is no necessary tie to magic here, the Black Pearl could easily have been as quick before the curse. The British Intercepter is said to be in a similar category to this. Not all ships travel at the same speed so I'd be thinking that magic is't playing a major part here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It depends**

But for the most part, no.

There's a total of 4 notable ships that we know:

- **The Flying Dutchman**

  This ship can sail through the water and also ascend. It is almost always with the wind and because of this, it is usually always faster than other ships including the Black Pearl. Unless the Black Pearl has the wind and/or the Dutchman doesn't, the Dutchman is faster.
- **The Black Pearl**

  This was raised by Davy Jones himself after it got sunk as The Wicked Wench. As part of the deal Jack made to Davy Jones, The Black Pearl became the fastest ship, so besides the Dutchman with the wind, The Black Pearl is the fastest ship and is because it got risen as the fastest ship-this could be interpreted as using magic for its speed, I however do not as it's more of a passive thing and doesn't actually use magic at all, it's simply one of Davy Jones' powers.
- **The HMS Endeavour**

  This ship was the ship of Lord Cutler Beckett and did not use any magic whatsoever. It simply was built well and had a lot of firepower.
- **The Queen Anne's Revenge**

  A good ship, and seems to be able to be controlled by a magic sword, also known as The Sword of Triton. When near other ships, if the user decides, they can control the masts and ropes and everything about the ships. This ship was under the command of Blackbeard who could and did use the sword to speed up the ship. It is now under the command of Barbossa who also used the sword for the same purposes.

---

So do ships get a speed boost from magic? Answer:

**Only when the Sword of Triton is near and is wielded to speed it up.**

Otherwise, all ships rely on how they're built for their speed, but the Black Pearl and/or The Flying Dutchman remain the fastest ships.

Comment: What about them travelling at the world's end and other side of the world

Comment: @codeczar That ship was just a random ship of Sao Fang's. It didn't have magical properties and was actually destroyed when they went over the falls. They just needed _a_ ship to get to At Word's End and Sao Fang's ship served that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The Black Pearl is said to be faster than most ships in the series, except the Flying Dutchman against the wind.

The Black Pearl was in its earlier life the Wicked Wench until Davy Jones saved it and Jack Sparrow from the depths and gave the resurrected ship magical speed.

All this is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Pearl).

Comment: But where did wikipedia get the info? Secondary sources are okay(ish) but we much prefer primary sources since we can then judge the validity of the statements made

Comment: @valorum agreed with you want some specific comment from books or movies to validate the claim

Comment: The Wiki references a book that Disney published covering Jack Sparrow's pre-pirate adventures on the Wicked Wench https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirates_of_the_Caribbean:_The_Price_of_Freedom